# Platform Exception while flutter paytm integration

Tags: flutter, dart, paytm

I am getting the following platform exception while integrating payTM to my flutter application using the payTM all in one sdk. Could anyone kindly please help me out?

> PlatformException(0, App Invoke is not allowed for this merchant,
> null, null)

Answer (score 1):

A code would be helpful in this case. But I recently integrated the PaytmAllInOneSDK in my application, so I think while calling the PaytmSDK you need to provide them a request Map and there is one key (`restrictAppInvoke`), you set it as true. Like this:

```
{
  "mid": <mid>,
  "orderId": <order_id>,
  "amount": <cash>,
  "txnToken": <txn_token>,
  "callbackUrl": <callbackUrl>,
  "isStaging": <true/false>,
  "restrictAppInvoke": true
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to restrict the app from invoking

Comment: @Laytoder Can you Please provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally enabled the staging flag to true, but all my URLs are pointing to Production links (initialize transaction, status check APIs).
So, make sure your whole environment is set to staging or production.